# SQL to sort by precedence

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to make calculations based on other calculations. These calcs are linked to accounting codes so I need to sort the codes in order of calculation precedence. Think of this: if x=.1(y) and y=.30(z), and z=1+2+3 then I need to calculate z then y and finally x.

The sample data below has my Xs and Ys and Zs represented as the accounting codes that I need to calculate.
For each row, I know that the first field has to be calculated before the second field. What I needed to accomplish is to get all the codes in order of calculation precedence.

Here is the code that I developed for solving the issue. I am leaving the question open hoping for a cleaner/better solution.

```
DECLARE @tbAccCodes TABLE (acct_code varchar(50),  process_order int NULL)  
INSERT INTO @tbAccCodes  
VALUES  
('195',NULL),
('220',NULL),
('225',NULL),
('301',NULL),
('304',NULL),
('620',NULL),
('500',NULL),
('510',NULL)

DECLARE @tbCodeDependency TABLE (calc_b4 varchar(50), this varchar(50))  
INSERT INTO @tbCodeDependency  
VALUES  
('195','500'),
('195','510'),
('220','500'),
('220','510'),
('225','220'),
('225','500'),
('225','510'),
('301','500'),
('301','510'),
('304','500'),
('304','510'),
('620','800')

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Order acct_code codes by calculation precedence
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DECLARE @left_acct_code varchar(50), @right_acct_code varchar(50), @left_process_order int, @right_process_order int
DECLARE curCalcPrecedence CURSOR FOR
    SELECT * FROM @tbCodeDependency

--The actual sorting by calculation precedence is done here
OPEN curCalcPrecedence
FETCH NEXT FROM curCalcPrecedence INTO @left_acct_code, @right_acct_code   --- left acct_code depends on right acct_code so left needs to be calculated b4 right
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @left_process_order = process_order FROM @tbAccCodes WHERE acct_code = @left_acct_code
    SELECT @right_process_order = process_order FROM @tbAccCodes WHERE acct_code = @right_acct_code

    IF (@left_process_order < @right_process_order)
    BEGIN
        GOTO Cont -- the order is already correct. Go to the next record
    END

    -- both process_order are null so update both to be at the end. Left first then right
    IF(@left_process_order IS NULL AND @right_process_order IS NULL) 
    BEGIN
        SELECT @left_process_order = MAX(ISNULL(process_order,0)) + 1 FROM @tbAccCodes 
        UPDATE @tbAccCodes SET process_order = @left_process_order WHERE  acct_code = @left_acct_code
        UPDATE @tbAccCodes SET process_order  = @left_process_order + 1 WHERE  acct_code = @right_acct_code
        GOTO Cont
    END

    IF(@left_process_order IS NOT NULL AND @right_process_order IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        -- they are in the wrong order because I already took care of both being not null in the correct order in the first check
        UPDATE @tbAccCodes SET process_order = process_order -1 WHERE process_order < @right_process_order 
        UPDATE @tbAccCodes SET process_order = @right_process_order -1 WHERE acct_code = @left_acct_code
        GOTO Cont
    END

    --left process_order is not null and right is null: update right to be at the end
    IF(@left_process_order IS NOT NULL AND @right_process_order IS NULL)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE  @tbAccCodes SET process_order = (SELECT MAX(process_order) FROM @tbAccCodes) + 1 WHERE  acct_code = @right_acct_code
        GOTO Cont
    END

    --last case left is null, right is not null: update left process order to be before right process order
    IF(@left_process_order IS NULL AND @right_process_order IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN 
        UPDATE @tbAccCodes SET process_order = process_order +1 WHERE process_order > @right_process_order -1 --  NOTE: > @right_process_order -1 is more efficient than >=right_process_order
        UPDATE @tbAccCodes SET process_order = @right_process_order WHERE acct_code = @left_acct_code
        GOTO Cont
    END

Cont:
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    --test line to see each iteration
    --select * from @tbAccCodes ORDER BY process_order 
    --end test
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    FETCH NEXT FROM curCalcPrecedence INTO @left_acct_code, @right_acct_code
END
CLOSE curCalcPrecedence
DEALLOCATE curCalcPrecedence

SELECT * FROM @tbAccCodes ORDER BY process_order
```

The data set is dynamic and circular references are not allowed.

If this adds to better understand the question, the initial requirement that took me here was:

Allow the end user to enter a % value and a list of codes to calculate a code. so
Code 240 = (user entered %) of the sum of the value of (user entered list of codes)
Code 301 = (user entered %) of the sum of the value of (user entered list of codes)
Code 195 = (user entered %) of the sum of the value of (user entered list of codes)
...

Furthermore, the "user entered list of codes" could be a single code, codes separated by commas, range of codes, and codes and code ranges to exclude from an included range.

Example: Code 240 = 10% of the sum of the value of the codes 301,304,200-299.99,-220,-260-270

Splitting the above using commas it would read:
Add 310
Add 304
Add all codes between 200 and 299.99
Remove code 220
Remove all codes from 260 to 270.

All of this just to 240. All of the codes included in the calculation of 240 need to be calculated before 240.

Then let's say that 195 = 5% of 240

Now, 240 needs to be calculated before 195.

Sorry for the long post but my original succinct text caused confusion due to ppl mistakenly thinking that the codes were actual numbers.

Thanks

Comment: can you explain the ordering(calculation precedence) i didn't get anything from the question

Comment: Yeah What @NoDisplayName said.. I don't understand the question.  Further I don't understand the desired sort.    Just throwing it out there - maybe you're looking for a row counter?

Comment: Are these Chart of Account codes?  and are therefore not numeric in the same way that phone numbers are not numeric. for example something like "a 3 series account is balance sheet"? That order_by column doesn't relate to your sample data - what do those numbers relate to, or how would you derive them? maybe it would help if you could tell us more about the problem you are solving.

Comment: Its still unclear what u r asking. What is **195 = 10 % of 304**. How come that be possible? @AleBel

Comment: That is read as calculate accounting code 195 as 10% of the results of the calculation for accounting code 304. I am not asking for the calculation, i just need the precedence sequence. Thanks

Comment: Since u told  -  **I am not asking for the calculation**, Have you got the result without precedence sequence? ie, like 225,220,301,195,304 because these results are generated after calculation, @AleBel

Comment: Are you saying that you have a table that has the equivalent of an Id / ParentId pair of columns, but you do not have a constant number of generations between the Id and the ParentId? In other words, you know that 220 comes before 195, but you have no idea at first if any other numbers appear on the list between them; you want to put all the numbers in order of precedence to display the single row in order. An rCTE would need a more basic Id, ParentId relationship than this, but it might still be possible...

Comment: @high Plains Grifter: Yes! That is exactly the task. After knowing the order, I can go ahead and do the calculations. Thanks

Comment: If I can use an analogy - you have a set of dominoes (or daisy-chain if you prefer), each domino is unique, and you need us to lay them out in a big line, matching the left hand side of one to the right hand side of the next. you have said there wont be any loops or forks and the list must be finite. To be able to achieve this we need to know the first and last domino. the first one wont have a dependency so the right hand side will be blank, the last one wont have a dependant so the left hand side will be blank.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Im right about the domino/daisy-chain scenario, see if this works for you. Note that I have an empty string for my "blank" ends so if you have spaces or nulls you will need to modify the script accordingly.

```
DECLARE @codes TABLE (dependant varchar(50), dependancy varchar(50))  
INSERT INTO @codes  
VALUES  
('','195'),
('195','304'),   
('225','290'),
('304','220'), 
('301','225'),  
('220','301'),  
('290','')

;with r_cte (code)
as (select dependant from @codes where dependancy = ''
    union all
    select dependant 
    from @codes c
        inner join r_cte r
            on r.code = c.dependancy
    where c.dependant <>  '')
select * from r_cte
```

Comment: Thanks, that was close but not the solution since the original data set that I supplied in the post was not used. The code that produces the data included is dynamic and only returns the dependency pairs. How did you choose 195 as the first one and 290 as the last one without sorting by precedence first? Also, if I use my original data adding your first and last row, it still doesn't work.  The solution needs to sort the dataset as it presented.

Comment: I have to fudge the data because I don't have all of your data. I cant daisy-chain without all the links. additionally I needed to create the start/end points as I said in the comment to your question. you shouldn't use ANY of my data because it is all made up. You don't need to use my first and last row. your data should have its own first and last row as outlined in my comment to your question.

Comment: @G B My first and last row have pairs. Should I just add rows to the first and last position with bogus data? This still doesn't work using the dataset provided:  
('','aaa'),  
('195','304'),    
('220','195'),    
('220','301'),    
('225','220'),    
('301','195'),     
('zzzzz','')

Comment: @AleBel the first and last in the sequence may not be the first/last in your result set. By definition the first in the sequence wont be dependant on anything so its "dependency" will be blank, similarly with the last in the sequence. If your data doesn't have a "first in sequence" then how can it be ordered?

Comment: With your data 220 is dependant on 195 & 301, 301 is also dependant on 195... am I missing something? how can this work?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I need to take a look back to the code that produces this list. Without that circular dependency your code worked, so I'll revisit it after making my necessary changes. Thanks again